# Flat the nested data into the top level object Amcharts

Tags: amcharts

Here is the structure of `data1`

```
var data1 = [{
"Date": "2016-07-09",
"StockList": [{"Name": "H1", "PNL2": 20, "NAV2" : 20}, {"Name": "H2", "PNL2": 20, "NAV2" : 20}]
"NAV": 26.28,
"PNL": 7.61
}, {
"Date": "2016-07-10",
"StockList": [{"Name": "H1", "PNL2": 20, "NAV2" : 20}, {"Name": "H2", "PNL2": 20, "NAV2" : 20}]
"NAV": 27.55,
"PNL": 12.89
}];
```

since nested data is not allowed in the `Amcharts`(if there is a way to deal with the nested data, that is better), is it possible flat the  into the top level object(I can not change the original inputed data). For example:

```
var data1 = [{
"Date": "2016-07-09",
"H1_PNL2": 20, 
"H1_NAV2" : 20
"H2_PNL2": 20, 
"H2_NAV2" : 20,
"NAV": 26.28,
"PNL": 7.61
}, {
"Date": "2016-07-10",
"H1_PNL2": 20, 
"H1_NAV2" : 20
"H2_PNL2": 20, 
"H2_NAV2" : 20,
"NAV": 27.55,
"PNL": 12.89
}];
```

In such `Amcharts` code:

```
var dataSet1 = new AmCharts.DataSet();
dataSet1.color = "#b0de09";
//create your field mappings for each valueField
dataSet1.fieldMappings = valueFields.map(function(valueField) {
  return {
    fromField: valueField,
    toField: valueField
  };
});
dataSet1.dataProvider = data;
dataSet1.categoryField = "Date";

chart.dataSets = [dataSet1];

// PANELS
var stockPanel = new AmCharts.StockPanel();
stockPanel.showCategoryAxis = true;
stockPanel.title = "PNL2";
stockPanel.eraseAll = false;
//stockPanel.addLabel(0, 100, "Click on the pencil icon on top-right to start drawing", "center", 16);

//create a graph for each valueField
valueFields.forEach(function(valueField) {
  var graph = new AmCharts.StockGraph();
  graph.title = valueField;
  graph.valueField = valueField;
  graph.bullet = "round";
  graph.bulletColor = "#FFFFFF";
  graph.bulletBorderColor = "#00BBCC";
  graph.bulletBorderAlpha = 1;
  graph.bulletBorderThickness = 2;
  graph.bulletSize = 7;
  graph.lineThickness = 2;
  graph.lineColor = "#00BBCC";
  graph.useDataSetColors = false;
  stockPanel.addStockGraph(graph);
});

chart.addPanel(stockPanel);
chart.write("chartdiv");
}

createStockChart(data1);
```

Here is my data structure

```
[{,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…},…]
  [0 … 99]
    0:{,…}
      CashLeft:0
      Commission:0
      Date:"/Date(1454428800000)/"
      NAV:0
      PNL:0
      Performance:[{
        0:{Stock: {Symbol: "1044 HK", Close: 66.714, Date: "/Date(1454428800000)/"}, Position: 0,…}
        1:{Stock: {Symbol: "1088 HK", Close: 10.9, Date: "/Date(1454428800000)/"}, Position: 0,…}
        2:{Stock: {Symbol: "12 HK", Close: 35.955, Date: "/Date(1454428800000)/"}, Position: 0,…}
```

And here is the code I write down

```
    function createStockChart(data) {
        var chart = new AmCharts.AmStockChart();

        data.forEach(function (data1) {
            data1.Performance.forEach(function (stockItem) {
                data1[stockItem.Symbol + "_PNL2"] = stockItem.PNL2;
            });
            //the following are completely optional - AmCharts won't look at StockList, but if you
            //want to conserve memory and don't need the StockList for anything else, you can remove
            //it
            data1.StockList.length = 0; //delete the StockList Array. Not necessary if you need it for something else
            delete data1.StockList; //remove the property from the object if you want. Also not necessary.
        });
```

But when I see the data structure it does not change, Maybe here is the problem that the List of stock(I mean the name(`Symbol`)) will be changed some days later, that means the properties of data will changed periodically, I don't know whether it is the point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your StockList will always have a `Name`, `PNL2` and `NAV2`, you can just loop through your data and assign the properties and values to the object prior to the rest of your code.

```
data1.forEach(function(arrayElement) {
  arrayElement.StockList.forEach(function(stockItem) {
    arrayElement[stockItem.Name + "_PNL2"] = stockItem.PNL2;
    arrayElement[stockItem.Name + "_NAV2"] = stockItem.NAV2;
  });
  //the following are completely optional - AmCharts won't look at StockList, but if you
  //want to conserve memory and don't need the StockList for anything else, you can remove
  //it
  arrayElement.StockList.length = 0; //delete the StockList Array. Not necessary if you need it for something else
  delete arrayElement.StockList; //remove the property from the object if you want. Also not necessary.
});
```

From there you can just run the rest of your code from my previous answer.

Demo:

```js
var data1 = [{
  "Date": "2016-07-09",
  "StockList": [{
    "Name": "H1",
    "PNL2": 20,
    "NAV2": 20
  }, {
    "Name": "H2",
    "PNL2": 20,
    "NAV2": 20
  }],
  "NAV": 26.28,
  "PNL": 7.61
}, {
  "Date": "2016-07-10",
  "StockList": [{
    "Name": "H1",
    "PNL2": 20,
    "NAV2": 20
  }, {
    "Name": "H2",
    "PNL2": 20,
    "NAV2": 20
  }],
  "NAV": 27.55,
  "PNL": 12.89
}];

data1.forEach(function(arrayElement) {
  arrayElement.StockList.forEach(function(stockItem) {
    arrayElement[stockItem.Name + "_PNL2"] = stockItem.PNL2;
    arrayElement[stockItem.Name + "_NAV2"] = stockItem.NAV2;
  });
  //the following are completely optional - AmCharts won't look at StockList, but if you
  //want to conserve memory and don't need the StockList for anything else, you can remove
  //it
  arrayElement.StockList.length = 0; //delete the StockList Array. Not necessary if you need it for something else
  delete arrayElement.StockList; //remove the property from the object if you want. Also not necessary.
});

console.log(data1);
```

Comment: it seems good, but here `function(data)` what is the `data`? Original is `data1` why here uses `data`?

Comment: `forEach` uses a callback for each iteration of the loop. The first parameter is the element of the array itself. [Array.forEach documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). I renamed the parameter to arrayElement to make it more obvious, but If you're not very experienced with JavaScript, I recommend getting more familiar with it first.

Comment: @ xorspark sorry it deon't work in my code please see the updated question

Comment: What values are you trying to graph? You need to clarify this as you started with one dataSet format and then changed it entirely. I can't help you if you keep changing the format. Also, you can't use "/Date(1454428800000)/" for dates. It needs to either be just a millisecond timestamp (the numeric value inside the Date() string) or a string-based timestamp (ex: YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss).

Comment: @ xorspark sorry the original data is just use for simplicity, I mean that for example, if two days later, `StockList` is replaced by `H3` `H4` instead of previous `H1` `H2`,  is it the reason why my code does not work?

Comment: You need to describe your problem in terms of your JSON output - I don't know what `H1`, `H2`, `H3` or `H4` are. I see a sub array called `Performance` - is that your StockList?  Post the full JSON output of the first element in your array and tell me what are the relevant values. Are you trying to display the `Close` value for each `Symbol`? Are all the elements in `Performance` under the same date as the top level `Date` property?

Comment: @ xorspark sorry actually it works I saw the wrong output....The Last the question, how can I preserve the properties only I want?`arrayElement[stockItem.Name + "_PNL2"] = stockItem.PNL2;` is  adding the new properties, for example, I want to preverse `data1` with only `NAV` ,`Date` ' `PNL`?

Comment: If you only want specific properties in your objects call `delete` on all the other properties that isn't `NAV`, `Date` and `PNL` My forEach call calls delete on `StockList` to remove it from each array element, for example.